# Excel - Use string for named range

Tags: excel, range

In a sheet, I have some named range - say test1, test2 and test3, with value 1, 4 an 7.

In another sheet, I have value 2, 1, 3 in columns A, and I would like to get the corresponding named range value in column B, respectively test2, test1 and test3 (4, 1 and 7).

My initial idea was to use concatenate to build the names of the ranges, but I have no idea how to get a named range by its name as a string.

How could I achieve what I want ?

Comment: Are they actually named **ranges** (i.e. those values are stored in cells) or just names defined with those constant values?

Comment: They are stored in cells.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are stored in cells, you can use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("test"&A1)
```

for example, will return 4 if cell A1 contains the value 2, since that is the value in test2.